# DAX - Calculate counts by using filter on multible columns

Tags: filter, dax, tabular

I am trying to get distinct counts by filters on tabular. Scenaria is like below.

`ID        ¦ProductName          ¦ color
----------¦ ------------------  ¦------
 1        ¦Crankarm             ¦    NA
 2        ¦Bearing Ball         ¦ Black
 1        ¦Bearing Ball         ¦ Black
 3        ¦Bearing Ball         ¦ Black
 4        ¦Blade                ¦ Black
 2        ¦Crankarm             ¦ Black
 5        ¦Bearing Ball         ¦ Black
 6        ¦Bearing Ball         ¦ Black
 6        ¦Blade                ¦ Black
 7        ¦Blade                ¦ Black
 7        ¦Blade                ¦ Black
 3        ¦Blade                ¦ Black
 5        ¦Crankarm             ¦ Black
 9        ¦Decal                ¦    NA`

I want to get 3 different Distinct Counts of 'ID'. Filters are like below:

 `1. ProductName ='Bearing Ball' and Color = 'Black' >(ID=2,1,3,5,6 > Distinct count:5)
 2. ProductName ='Blade'        and Color = 'Black' >(ID=4,6,7,7,3 > Distinct count:4)
 3. ProductName ='Crankarm'     and Color = 'Black' >(ID=2,5 > Distinct count:2)`

And will sum all 3 distinct counts. Final result of my measure will be: 5+4+2 = 11.

I calculated measures by below code for all 3 products separetly. And SUM result of 3 measures in a other measure.(FinalResult:= [BB]+[BL]+[CR] ) but it didn't work.

`BB:= CALCULATE (
    DISTINCTCOUNT ( Product[ID] ),
    FILTER (
        VALUES (Product ),
        Product[ProductName] = "Bearing Ball" && Product[Color] = "Black"   )
)`

`BL:= CALCULATE (
    DISTINCTCOUNT ( Product[ID] ),
    FILTER (
        VALUES (Product ),
        Product[ProductName] = "Blade" && Product[Color] = "Black"   )
)`

`CR:= CALCULATE (
    DISTINCTCOUNT ( Product[ID] ),
    FILTER (
        VALUES (Product ),
        Product[ProductName] = "Crankarm" && Product[Color] = "Black"   )
)`

I can't get distinct counts in same query by adding OR because, different ProductName can have same ID. And if use in same query, i will lost them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One easy way is create a calculated column like this:

```
IDNameColor = [ID] &"-"& [ProductName]  & "-" & [Color]
```

Then use that calculated column in a measure like this to get the count of products:

```
Total Count :=
CALCULATE (
    DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'Product'[IDNameColor] ),
    FILTER (
        ALL ( 'Product' ),
        ( [Color] = "Black"
            && [ProductName] = "Bearing Ball" )
            || ( [Color] = "Black"
            && [ProductName] = "Blade" )
            || ( [ProductName] = "Crankarm"
            && [Color] = "Black" )
    )
)
```

You can remove the `ALL('Product')` function if you want it to be affected by filters.

Aleternatively if you don't want to create a calculated column the measure can be like this:

```
Total Count :=
COUNTAX (
    FILTER (
        DISTINCT ( 'Product' ),
        ( [Color] = "Black"
            && [ProductName] = "Bearing Ball" )
            || ( [Color] = "Black"
            && [ProductName] = "Blade" )
            || ( [ProductName] = "Crankarm"
            && [Color] = "Black" )
    ),
    [ID] & [ProductName]
        & [Color]
)
```

Comment: First code worked fine. Second didn't. Thanks a lot.